# Google Drive Auto-Expire - Unshare Multiple Files Simultaneously?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Good Evening! I'm Aaron Ayres, an 8th grade mathematics teacher at Noblesville West Middle School in Noblesville, Indiana.  Recently for a school-wide incentive my school is using Google Drive to share a "pass" that grants nominated students access to rewards and other treats during the month they are nominated.  We typically have about 80 students who are nominated on a monthly basis for their hard work - each educator in the building nominates one student each month based on multiple criteria.

Instead of having to manually go through my folder and un-share the individual passes at the end of the month, I have been researching for a more efficient method of allowing the passes to expire.  I came across Amit Argawal's Auto-expire script (http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-expire-google-drive-links/27509/) and I think it could potentially work but it only expires one file at a time.  Is there a way I can modify the script (or create a new script) to reference multiple, sharable links in the script editor so the sharing access to each individual students' pass expires at the end of the month?  In other words, is there a way for the script to expire all 80+ passes at the same date and time?  I'm a novice to Google Scripts so I'm wondering if I am not formatting my list or URL references correctly so the script recognizes multiple files, or perhaps I could revise the script to recognize an array of links instead of a single variable url link.

Thanks in advance for the assistance!

Comment: Your question is to general.  It doesn't include any code.  Consider joining the [Google Apps Script Group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769) and asking the question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have the full [script](http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-expire-google-drive-links/27509/) at your hand.Please give the URLs in a list, separated with commas. Are the passwords different for each student? Otherwise you could have just added the URL of the folder without changing the original script at all.

However, Please try changing these portions of the script:

```
// Enter the full list of URLs(separated with comma) of the public Google Drive file or folder

var URL_LS = ["https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_NmiOlCM-VTcFp6U1hydTM2MzVCY3AzMUpuTEtVWUhXRXNz", "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_NmiOlCM-VTNXFqOU1jTG5JdHJVQ3ZGUGNqZklJNWludllr/view?usp=sharing"] ;
var URL_LN = URL_LS.length;

// Enter the expiry date in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format 

var EXPIRY_TIME  = "2016-02-18 09:46";
```

And again,replace the `autoExpire()` as follows:

```
function autoExpire() {

  var id, asset, i, email, users;

  try {

    for (var j = 0; j < URL_LN; j++) {
    var URL = URL_LS[j];
    var id = URL.match(/[-\w]{25,}/g);

    if (id) {

      id = id[id.length-1];

      asset = DriveApp.getFileById(id) ? DriveApp.getFileById(id) : DriveApp.getFolderById(id);

      if (asset) {

        asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.NONE);  
        asset.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.NONE); 

        users = asset.getEditors();
        for (i in users) {
          email = users[i].getEmail();
          if (email !== "") {
            asset.removeEditor(email);
          }
        }

        users = asset.getViewers();
        for (i in users) {
          email = users[i].getEmail();
          if (email !== "") {
            asset.removeViewer(email);
          }
        }  

      }
    }
   }

  } catch (e) {

    Logger.log(e.toString());

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance!  When the files I want to expire have one user each, the script will un-share all of the files in the list correctly, but if I test the script with files shared with multiple users/editors, the script will stop after expiring the first file in the URL list.  Is there a way to force the script to continue working to expire files shared with multiple users?  The files in question are shared to me and then I share the files to the students so each file I need to expire at the end of the month have at least 3 users attached (including me).  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a silly mistake. Just run the first for loop with `j` or some other variable. The `i` was having a conflict later in the function with other for loops. Also change this one: `var URL = URL_LS[j];`. I hope it should work now!

Comment: Edited the function.

Comment: As I noticed that variable was referenced earlier in the script and started working on a fix I received your reply.  Now the script works perfectly now!  Thanks for taking the time to help!